# Crop multiple scalable images from one image using css and create carousel with them

Tags: css

I have an image that contains a handful of maps and I am trying to display each individually in an img carousel with a slider of thumbnails. I want to crop each individual map out and have it scale like its its own image file. Trying to use CSS as opposed to cropping out new files in a photo editor. I've looked around and found a lot on css cropping, but can't figure out how to make the crop scale.

This is the original image-     https://www.floridamemory.com/FMP/maps/large/fmc0001.jpg

I haven't built the carousel but I created classes that would be used to change the crop of the image, but can't get the images to scale.

`enter code here`https://codepen.io/admaloch/pen/QWVxgzz?editors=1111

Is it possible to do this with just css?

Comment: Please don't make more work for other people by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/), for Stack Exchange to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By Stack Exchange policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post please see: [How does deleting work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221)

Comment: Additionally, do not add a link to your code. See [mre] and [edit] the question to contain all relevant code within the question itself. Links can rot, people might not be able to access the website, there might be licensing issues etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can do it with just CSS and your method can be made to work.

But you have to be quite accurate with your measurements, and most importantly to get the aspect ratio of an individual map correct.

You can't use the 100% relative settings on both width and height given these will change with viewport changes as you have things set up.

One way to get started would be to set the width of main-img to 100% and then aspect-ratio to something sensible (e.g. that makes sure the Keys stay visible). I think something roughly like aspect-ratio: 2 / 3 should do it but up to you how much of the above and below each map you want to include.

Coupled with accurate measurement of the %s this should be sufficient.

Let me know if you get stuck though.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I tried what you said and for some reason i still can't get it to work properly. I set the aspect ratio and each map position class looks good when I'm on a large screen in full view, but as soon as I change the screen width the images won't scale. I'm not sure the object-fit property is doing anything?